# try to run flutter project failed

Tags: flutter

** i have follow the guide,but it did not work, simple console log after 'flutter run':**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         16.2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**detail console log after 'flutter run -v':**

```
    [  +43 ms] executing: [/Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [  +43 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [        ] origin/beta
    [        ] executing: [/Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [   +7 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [        ] beta
    [        ] executing: [/Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    [        ] executing: [/Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [  +12 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [        ] f37c235c32fc15babe6dc7b7bc2ee4387e5ecf92
    [        ] executing: [/Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
    [  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
    [        ] 3 weeks ago
    [   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags

[ +264 ms] [ +237 ms] Building bundle
[        ] [   +1 ms] Writing asset files to /Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter_proj/myapp/czc/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets
[ +258 ms] [ +279 ms] Wrote /Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter_proj/myapp/czc/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/flutter_assets
[  +10 ms] [  +10 ms] "flutter bundle" took 1,333ms.
[ +545 ms] /Users/chengzhichao/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar: error: I/O error.
[   +8 ms] 20 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 15 up-to-date
[  +14 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
[        ] > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to getfull insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 4s
[ +443 ms] Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed)
[  +17 ms] "flutter run" took 10,362ms.
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:393:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:296:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:41:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:378:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:287:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:262:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:391:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:372:18)
#9      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#12     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#15     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#16     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#17     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#18     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:295:13)
#19     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#20     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#26     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#27     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#28     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

print after `flutter docter -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 0.9.4 at /Users/chengzhichao/project/flutter
    • Framework revision f37c235c32 (3 weeks ago), 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400
    • Engine revision 74625aed32
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/chengzhichao/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255
    • ios-deploy 2.0.0
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.2.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 182.4999

[✓] VS Code (version 1.28.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.19.0

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • MIX 2 • c54c0f85 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
```

Comment: I am not really sure, but this may occur due to lack of permissions for gradlew file upon the compilation. Depending on OS(like UNIX systems) request additional permissions to build a app.

Comment: Please consider [filing a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) against Flutter, including the logs and `flutter doctor` output above.

Comment: I have tried to give the build directory the highest permissions. But no effect. The same is true on virtual Android devices. Both virtual and real IOS devices are available for normal use.

Comment: I also tried to check out master, but it didn't work.

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23137